# If there is only one God, why are there so many different religions?

Tags: religion

If there is only one God, then why is there so many "different" religions an beliefs about the "same" God?

Comment: What makes you think the religious all have the same god?

Comment: Well,, do they? I mean, the religions here in America.

Comment: Which religions specifically?

Comment: I've met Christian pastors who says Mormons has it wrong, vice-versa.Who's right?

Comment: Yes, so why do you think the 'Christian' and Mormon gods are the same?

Comment: I assumed they were,,are they?

Comment: "Who's right?" is not a question we can answer here. http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3527/20

Comment: I understand! I apologize for the inconvenience!

Comment: Perhaps you could ask a question about the differences between the trinitarian God and the Mormon God. (Or it's probably already been asked. Have a search first)

Comment: Lol, I didn't even know it was such a thing..i guess I'm over my head here. But that's why I came to this web site, because I want to learn

Comment: @user10314 to learn ... you got that right!

Comment: AaronKorn what does that mean?

Comment: Are you asking about religions such as Islam, Buddhism, Hinduism, etc. or do you really men differing Denominations such as Protestant, and Catholic?

Comment: This is simply not a question that would be appropriate for the C.SE, and should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

From a Christian perspective, man is naturally religious and therefore man desires to know God. Over the course of many centuries, man has therefore come up with different religions to describe what God is like and what God requires.

Christianity believes that man through reason can know that God exists, but needs special revelation from God in order to truly know what God wants. The central claim of Christianity is that **God himself has taken human form in Jesus Christ and revealed to us what he is like**.

In other religions, men tell us what God is like and what he wants (hence the differences in religion based on men's opinions). In Christianity, God becomes a man to tell us what he is like and what he wants.

Comment: LoveTheFaith  can you please paraphrase or say that in a different way. I "Think" I understand

Comment: I do not know what you mean. Say what in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

You might just as well ask, As my country has only one government, why are there so many political parties? Why are there so many different theories in physics or chemistry? Why do people have different ideas about economics?

If people had perfect knowledge, then by definition we would all know the truth about God and we would all believe the same thing.

But we don't have perfect knowledge. People disagree about lots of things. Different people formulate different theories to explain the observed facts. Religion is no different than any other field of study. In the end, on any given question some people will turn out to be right and others wrong. Or maybe it will turn out that we're all wrong and the truth is something that no one thought of.

Comment: @ Jay I really do appreciate that..very helpful.

Comment: @ Jay why do others would rather flag, delete or close my post when they could just simply give me an answer the way you did? Smh..

Comment: @user10314 Beats me. I've add a number of conversations on Stackexchange sites with people who would rather close a question than answer it or even ignore it.